# Bigquery: Joining 2 tables one having repeated records and one with count ()

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I want to join tables after unnest arrays in Table:1 but the records duplicated after the join because of the unnest.

**Table:1**

```
| a | d.b | d.c |
-----------------
| 1 |  5  |  2  |
-   -------------
|   |  3  |  1  |
-----------------
| 2 |  2  |  1  |
```

**Table:2**

```
| a |  c  |  f  |
-----------------
| 1 |  12 | 13  |
-----------------
| 2 | 14  | 15  |
```

I want to join table 1 and 2 on `a` but I need also to have the output of:

```
| a | d.b | d.c |  f  |  h  |  Sum(count(a))
---------------------------------------------
| 1 |  5  |  2  | 13  | 12  |
-   -------------     -     -       1
|   |  3  |  1  |     |     |
---------------------------------------------
| 2 |  2  |  1  | 15  | 14  |       1
```

`a` can be repeated in table 2 for that I need to count(a) then select the sum after join.

*My problem is when I'm joining I need the nested and repeated record to be the same as in the first table but when use aggregation to get the sum I can't group by struct or arrays so I `UNNEST` the records first then use `ARRAY_AGG` function but also there was an issue in the sum.*

```
SELECT
 t1.a,
 t2.f,
 t2.h,
 ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT(t1.db)) as db,
 ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT(t1.dc)) as dc,
 SUM(t2.total) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT
    a,
    d.b as db,
    d.c as dc
  FROM
    `table1`,
    UNNEST(d) AS d,
  ) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    a,
    f,
    h,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
  FROM
    `table2`
  GROUP BY
    a,f,h) AS t2
ON
  t1.a = t2.a
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3
```

> Note: the error is in the total number after the sum it is much higher than expected all other data are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your table 2 contains is not unique for column `a`.

Lets assume that the table 2 looks like this:

| a | c | f |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 13 |
| 2 | 14 | 15 |
| 1 | 100 | 101 |

There are two rows where `a` is `1`. Since `b` and `f` are different, the grouping does not solve this ( `GROUP BY a,f,h) AS t2`) and `counts(*) as total` is one for each row.

| a | c | f | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 13 | 1 |
| 2 | 14 | 15 | 1 |
| 1 | 100 | 101 | 1 |

In the next step you join this table to your table 1. The rows of table1 with value `1` in column `a` are duplicated, because table2 has two entries. This lead to the fact that the sum is too high.

Instead of unnesting the tables, I recommend following approach:

```sql
-- Creating of sample data as given:
with tbl_A as (select  1 a, [struct(5 as b,2 as c),struct(3,1)] d union all select 2,[struct(2,1)] union all select null,[struct(50,51)]),
tbl_B as (select 1 as a,12 b, 13 f union all select 2,14,15 union all select 1,100,101 union all select null,500,501)

-- Query:

select *
from tbl_A A
left join
(Select a,array_agg(struct(b,f)) as B, count(1) as counts from tbl_B group by 1) B
on ifnull(A.a,-9)=ifnull(B.a,-9)
```

Comment: The answer is out of context my point is that the count of a in table 2 are too much than the actual count I guess that the duplication in the count occurs at the join, other data is all correct.

Comment: How to use `WITH` and `UNION` if my table contains millions of records ? Knowing that the records are different type in each column? @Samuel

Comment: @MohamedHaydar both tables in the `WITH` statement are sample tables with the data you provided.

Comment: Ok I provided samples, but my data consists of million of records how should I implement my query?

Comment: Please replace the `tbl_A` by yourdataset.table1 and `tbl_B` by yourdataset.table2

Comment: I guess I've found the issue but another error I have faced is that when I `UNNEST` a NULL RECORD all the joined record removed from the data

Comment: For joining, I replace `null` by the value -9.